quarkus cognito user pool extension proxy config
we are trying to use quakus cognito userpool extension with a proxy. As mentioned in the documentation, we configure the proxy in the application.yaml as follow:
quarkus:
  cognito-user-pools:
    sync-client:
      type: apache
      apache:
        proxy:
          enabled: true
          endpoint: http://proxyhost:proxyPort
          username: username
          password: password

when running the app, we get following error:
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n","errorType":"software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.CognitoIdentityProviderException","**errorMessage":"Service returned HTTP status code 407 (Service: CognitoIdentityProvider, Status Code: 407, Request ID: null)**"}
{"timestamp":"2024-05-06T10:08:51.137Z","sequence":865,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger"

Could someone help us please. Thanks in advance
use cognito user pool quarkus extension with proxy
